# "Homotopy theoretic" form of Poincaré duality

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, poincare-duality

The [ncatlab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Poincar%C3%A9+duality) on Poincaré duality states the following:

> Let $X$ be a Poincaré duality space of dimension $d$. Then there is a quasi-isomorphism
>
> $$C^*(X) \rightarrow \Sigma^{-d}C_*(X)$$
>
> between the chain complex of ordinary cohomology of $X$ with the $d$-fold de-suspension of the chain complex of ordinary homology of $X$. This is such that the image in homology is (up to sign) the traditional Poincaré duality isomorphism.

The reference they give for this result is [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.6198) of E. J. Malm, Theorem 2.5.2.

Malm does not appear to provide a proof of this result, but instead states it in his background section, and I cannot find a reference of the result therein.

I find even the statement of this result in the paper by Malm hard to digest. Some knowledge is assumed, such as a canonical action of $C_*(\Omega X)$ on a ground ring $k$, and notation such as $k[\pi_1(X)]$ is used, which is unfamiliar to me.

Where can I find a proof of this result?

Also, what is the action of $C_*(\Omega X)$ on $k$, and what is $k[\pi_1(X)]$?

Comment: $k [\pi_1 (X)]$ is probably the group ring, i.e. the (possibly non-commutative) $k$-algebra generated by the elements of $\pi_1 (X)$ with multiplication as in $\pi_1 (X)$. This is usually denoted $k \pi_1 (X)$ though, as far as I know... Anyway, the point is that a local system of $k$-modules on a path connected space $X$ is the same thing as a $k$-module with an action of $\pi_1 (X)$.

Comment: Have you read that later, on page 12, the author provides a proof of theorem 2.5.2 ?